# Using the service data in the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have placed the service and the controller in the same js file. So Im trying to fetch the data from the service and use it in my html. In my code Im able to generate the data from the service but not able to assign it to a `$scope` in the controller and use it in the html. So how do I get the data and assign it to the `$scope` so that I can use it in my html.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.factory('factoryServices',function($http){
    var newObject = {};
    var _getChart= function(){
        $http.get("http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json")
        .success(function(data, status){
            if(data) {
                return data;
            }
        }).error(function(data,status){
           return error;
        });
    }
    newObject.getChart = _getChart;
    return newObject;
});


app.controller("chartController",function($scope,$http,factoryServices){
  factoryServices.getChart($scope.chartServicesCompleted); 
  $scope.chartServicesCompleted = function(data){
        $scope.serviceResponse = data;
    }
})
```

Comment: Some good answer have been placed already, but I'd also like to touch on the fact that you're still using .success() and .error() for handling your promises. I highly recommend you switch over to .then(), because .success() and .error() have been deprecated and completely removed in 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite your code like this, it should work as expected:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.factory('factoryServices',function($http){
    var newObject = {};
    var _getChart= function(){
        return $http.get("http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json")
        .then(function(response){
            if(response.data) {
                return response.data;
            }
        }, function(response){
           console.error("getChart failed with ",response);
        });
    }
    newObject.getChart = _getChart;
    return newObject;
});
```

and your controller

```
app.controller("chartController",function($scope,$http,factoryServices){
    factoryServices.getChart().then(chartServicesCompleted);

    function chartServicesCompleted(data){
        $scope.serviceResponse = data;
    }
})
```

The reason your initial code doesn't work, is because your `getChart` doesn't actually take an argument. So passing your callback like this: `getChart($scope.chartServicesCompleted)` doesn't do anything. In the rewritten code, I've made it so the `getChart` function returns the promise created by `$http.get(..)` which then allows you to use `.then([callback])` in your controller.

Comment: Your code is the most correct out of all the answer, no clue why you got downvoted.

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren I agree. I've also edited my answer so the rewrite uses `then` instead of the deprecated `success` and `error` functions.

Comment: when I run the file in browser (chrome). It ends up in infinite loop...why is it happening?

Comment: @devanya It shouldn't. There's no statement in the above code that could cause that. Can you try to add some `console.log(..)` calls to check where your code starts looping or perhaps share your exact code so I can review it?

Answer (score 0):

you are passing a callback function but not handling inside the service method.

do change as

```
 var _getChart= function(callback){
        $http.get("http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json")
        .success(function(data, status){
            callback(data);
        }).error(function(data,status){
             callback(data);
        });
    }
```

now `factoryServices.getChart($scope.chartServicesCompleted);` will work
you can make more generic by handling **success and error** callback separately.

or one more way is to implement the success and error logic inside your controller.

but do not forget to check the function type i.e

```
if(typeof callback == 'function'){
   callback(data);
}
```

Edit: as per advanced you call implement promises.

if you are using angular version 1.6, the success and error methods have been depreciated.

secondly you can do inside service return the http object

```
var _getChart= function(){
           return $http.get("http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json");            
        }
```

and then handle the promise in the controller like

```
factoryServices.getChart().then(successMethod, error method);
```

Comment: Get rid of callbacks and use promises. Are you comming from jQuery? ^^

Comment: we all know about promises, the person seems to be new learner. you need to teach them step wise

Comment: now the person has an idea of callback too never mind.

Answer (score 0):

Let the service return the promise to the controller. ex:

```
 var _getChart= function(){
    return $http.get("http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json");
}
```

and in the controller handle the promise. Use 'then' instead

```
factoryServices.getChart().then(function(response){var theDate = response.data},function(error){});
```

you can declare methods instead in the controller for handling the success and error

```
factoryServices.getChart).then(onSuccess,onError);
```

Don use the .success method and .error method. They dont't behave as other promises. So get used to 'then'

You really don't need to handle errors in the service method.I use angular interceptors in most of the cases. Check em out. But sometimes you need to handle the error in the controller. So its good to get the callback in the controller

Comment: Your answer is mostly correct, but the first couple of lines are blatantly incorrect, the newObject is the same instance at all times; Angular services are singletons by nature. I highly suggest you remove that part as it might give the wrong idea to new angular developers.